# Is there any way to trigger React.useEffect from different component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Imagine two components like this in React:

```js
import MyComponent2 from "./components/MyComponent2";
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [myState, setMyState] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect triggered");
  }, [myState]);

  return <MyComponent2 myState={myState} setMyState={setMyState} />;
}
```

```js
import React from "react";

export default function MyComponent2(props) {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");

  function handleChange(e) {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
    let list = props.myState;
    list.push(`${e.target.value}`);
    props.setMyState(list);

    console.log(props.myState);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={inputValue}
        name="text"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see I am making changes with props.setMyState line in second component. State is changing but Somehow I could not trigger React.useEffect in first component even tough It is connected with [myState]. Why ?

In short form of my question : I can not get "useEffect triggered" on my console when i make changes in input

Comment: You're modifying your state by using `list.push()`, you should create a new array and add your item to the end of that rather than modifying your `list` state in place with `.push()`. See [Adding to an array](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#adding-to-an-array)

Comment: Treat state as immutable https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of providing `myState` and `setMyState` to `MyComponent2`, you should only provide `setMyState` and use the [functional update argument](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) in order to access the current state.

In your `handleChange` function you are currently mutating the React state ([modifying it directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)):

```js
let list = props.myState; // This is an array that is state managed by React
list.push(`${e.target.value}`); // Here, you mutate it by appending a new element
props.setMyState(list);
// ^ You update the state with the same array here,
// and since they have the same object identity (they are the same array),
// no update occurs in the parent component
```

Instead, you should set the state to a **new** array (whose object identity differs from the current array):

```js
props.setMyState(list => {
  const newList = [...list];
  newList.push(e.target.value);
  return newList;
});

// A concise way to write the above is like this:
// props.setMyState(list => [...list, e.target.value]);
```